# What's the [etiquette] for using [manners]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

- [etiquette](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette): [14 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette)
- [manners](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manners): [20 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manners)

([2 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette+manners) have both tags.)

Both tags have no tag description.

Etiquette ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/etiquette)):

> the set of rules or customs that control accepted behaviour in particular social groups or social situations

Manners ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manners)):

> ways of behaving toward people, esp. ways that are socially correct and show respect for their comfort and their feelings

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiquette) redirects manners to etiquette.

Looking at the questions, it seems like [etiquette](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette) and [manners](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manners) are used interchangeably.

Is there are difference between **etiquette** and **manners** great enough to warrant two distinct tags? If so, what is it - where to draw the line? Else, which one should be master?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I think this is a superb question. Community defines manners and etiquette, so this community should decide :-)